# Swift Initialization - Why are multiple init functions being called?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, init

Here's is my class with override inits

```
class BottomView: UIView {

    // MARK: - initilization

   override init() {
        println("init")
        super.init()
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        println("init frame")
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        println("init decoder")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        println("setup")
    }
}
```

I then initialize in my ViewController with the following code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let bottomView = BottomView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.height/2.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height/2.0)
        bottomView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin
        self.view.addSubview(bottomView)

    }
}
```

And my output is

```
init
init frame
setup
setup
```

So my question is, why is init(frame:) being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super.init()` calls `self.init(frame:...)`. Essentially, it's just their way of saying that `frame` is optional; if you don't pass it, they assign a frame of `(0,0,0,0)`.

```
func init() {
  self.init(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0));
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I've changed init to a convenience override init() and call self.init(frame) rather than super.init.   Do you know if there is a place to see what the default initializers are for each class?  Had to do the same thing with a UITableView, but default is init(frame: style:)

Comment: Why are you bothering to override `init()` at all? It looks like you just want to put your `setup` code into `init(frame:)` and leave `init()` doing its default thing.

Comment: I thought swift requires having a certain init() functions, even if overriding others.  When I remove my override init() function I get error "Missing argument for parameter 'frame' in call" on the line let bottomView = BottomView()

Comment: If you want to instantiate it that way, you'll have to override `init` since subclasses don't directly inherit their initializers in swift. I just meant leave `init` just calling `super.init` and nothing else.

Comment: Good point.  I guess I changed it for readability, since my problem in the first place was that it wasn't clear to me why init(frame) was being called.  You know what best practice is?

Comment: Determine what your use case is for each initializer; if you find that you're always initializing with `init` and never with `init(frame)`, don't bother overriding `init(frame)`. If it's the opposite, don't bother overriding `init`. If you find yourself using both in different situations, consider having `init` just call `super.init` unless there's specific `init`-only steps to take that you wouldn't want to take in `init(frame)`.